# Need guidance with efficient method to fetch all the news

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Let's assume a user is following thousands of other people,

These people send news regularly, and in his/her page, our user wants to see the recent news (paginated) from these people only.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

This is what I'm doing currently:

1. Create a table called `following` in database, each follow is added here, `id`, `user_id`, `following_user_id`
2. Get a list of user's following_user_ids
3. fetch all news WHERE `user_id` (news poster id) is `IN(...following_user_ids...)`

For example if our user's id is 1:

```
SELECT `following_user_id` FROM `following` WHERE `user_id` = 1; /* This is used in the IN() below */

SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `user_id` IN (4,11,7,...following_user_ids....) ORDER BY `id` DESC limit 50 offset 0

/* Of course the `user_id` is indexed in the `news` table */
```

But if the user is following thousands of people and the `news` table is huge, I'm assuming the `IN (... thousands of IDs ...)` will be very slow?

So, is there a more efficient way to do this?

### EDIT:

In case any one also has this issue, just stick with the IN method, it is a lot faster than JOIN in my case.

Comment: This is basically a textbook case for a JOIN. If you don't know how those work, search a bit. It's a very basic cornerstone of any SQL-based database and there are thousands of tutorials out there.

Comment: @Vilx So something like this will be faster? `select * from news JOIN following ON news.user_id = following.following_user_id WHERE following.user_id=1;`

Comment: Speed will depend on many things. You'll definitely need to add indexes to all the user_id columns, but then also the size of the table and the capacity of the server will play a role. If you get to millions of rows and hundreds of gigabytes per table, then you'll have to think about some more advanced strategies like replication or caches or whatever. Big data is hard. But don't worry about that until you get there. Most people don't have this problem anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    news.*
from
    news
    join following on news.user_id=following.following_user_id
where
    following.user_id=1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know the JOIN would be faster.

Comment: (Plus `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.)

Answer (score 1):

**Pagination**

`OFFSET` has a problem.  As he pages forward/backward and others are inserting new rows, he will miss stories or see the same story twice on consecutive pages.

The solution is to "remember where you left off".  More: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

**JOIN**

The `JOIN` approach is cleaner, but not necessarily faster.  In either case, the end result is a large list of stories, of which he is only interested in a page's worth.  Shoveling the rest around is costly.

The fix for this is to find only the ids of the stories while finding the page's worth.  *Then* look up (via another `JOIN`) the rest of the data for each story.

**Prebuilt list**

Still, if there are thousands of followed people (or millions of followers, in the case of Trump), it gets quite costly.  There is a technique for making the `SELECT` faster at the cost of `INSERTs` needing to run around and store information.

Have a new 3-column table:  (1) follower_id, (2) timestamp, (3) story_id.  Whenever a story is posted, one row *per follower* is added to this table.  When a follower wants the latest stories, it is sitting right in this table (or at least the ids are).

More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/lists

Comment: Thank you very much, the "remember where you left off" method seems very interesting!

I'm still testing different approaches, so seeded the database with 3 million news, and followed ~300 people and the following query takes 2 seconds:

`SELECT * FROM news INNER JOIN following ON following.followable_id = news.user_id AND following.followable_type = 'user' AND following.user_id = 1 ORDER BY news.id DESC LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0`

While the `IN()` method takes 3.5 seconds.

I don't think these numbers are normal (they seem too much), so I will be testing more to see what's the issue...

Comment: @J.Doe - Did you add any indexes? However for 3M rows on a typical desktop machine, 2 seconds sounds plausible. Do you really expect to have this much data in production?

Comment: @Vilx, Yes, all the necessary columns are indexed (and yes, I expect more than 3M rows in a year), however I realized `Innodb_buffer_pool_size` was very low, after increasing it and analyzing table, the `IN()` method now takes 800ms, while the `JOIN` takes 1.3s, still high though, so what I ended up doing, is to limit the `news` by date range (e.g. last week) without ORDER BY, this way the query executes in just `20ms`! and I paginate and sort the results on the user side with DataTables. And if the result is empty, I then query database for all the results for that user.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit your search by using the 'LIMIT' function, that will need to be updated everytime the user want more information:

```
  LIMIT [offset,] row_count;
```

Putting it in your example would be something like this, saving this select in a temporary table variable:

```
  SELECT * FROM `following_user_ids` ORDER BY `id` DESC limit rowcount offset offset_variable;
```

If you want to put in the example of a social media, you can update the limit everytime the user asks for more posts, so that the user will be able to see the posts of several of the he follows.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I already have a limit in my query (`limit 50 offset 0`), you probably missed it. I'm more concerned about the `IN()` part getting too long.

Comment: But, you can use the limit to the followers too, changing the offset and row_count, but then you'll have to update the search with different values to these variables if a person asks for new posts.

Comment: That is not the best way, but it is a faster one.